# regarding distorted back button on iOS app using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I am using `UINavigationController` in my app. In most of the iPhones I tested its fine. However, on an iPhone4 the back button is sometimes (not always) distorted.

[image: screenshot for distorted back button]

Can anyone kindly tell me if theres something I have missed or if there is something I should do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a standard UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot, but check your logs to see if you're get any errors related to core animation and/or bad transforms. I've seen something like this before.